# Can't save ini file in html

Tags: javascript, html

I can't save a file named `config.ini` in HTML using JavaScript.
Here is my code:

```js
function output() {
var name = 'config.ini';
            var blob = new Blob(["[Identifiers] \nClientID="+document.getElementById("third").value+"\n[State]\nState="+document.getElementById("first").value+"\nDetails="+document.getElementById("second").value+"\n[Images]\nLargeImage="+document.getElementById("fourth").value+"\nSmallImage="+document.getElementById("fifth").value+"\nLargeImageTooltip= \nSmallImageTooltip="], {type : 'text/html'})
         saveAs(blob, name);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first" placeholder="State" />
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="second" placeholder="Details" />
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="third" placeholder="Client ID" />
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="fourth" placeholder="Large Image" />
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="fifth" placeholder="Small Image" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="output()" />
```

When I click the `submit` button, nothing happens.

Thank you.

Comment: can you share the `saveAs` function you are using?

Comment: What environment are you using?  Web server?  Node.js?  A mobile platform of some sort?

Comment: @Luca I tried FileSaver.js too, and id didn't work too.

Comment: "too"? What else did you try? Why didn't "FileSaver.js" work?

Comment: document.saveAs(), window.saveAs(), just saveAs() and FileSaver.js, that didn't work for the same reason, I click the button and nothing happened.

Comment: Always first check in the developer console for the error

Comment: @Deep with file-saver, require is not defined.
in others, window.saveAs is not a function, document.saveAs is not a function, and saveAs is not defined

Comment: @Gabriel : You need to fix these issues to make it work. i  think saveAs is a function provided by FileSaver.js , Just check if you have added require.js and it is needed in your code.